# relation between intersection and addition of subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Could anyone help me to proof the foloowings

Suppose $\mathcal{V}_1,\mathcal{V}_2$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then
\begin{align*}
&(i)(\mathcal{V}_1+\mathcal{V}_2)^{\perp}=\mathcal{V}_1^{\perp}\cap\mathcal{V}_2^{\perp}.\\
&(ii)(\mathcal{V}_1\cap \mathcal{V}_2)^{\perp}=\mathcal{V}_1^{\perp} + \mathcal{V}_2^{\perp}.\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x \in (V_1 + V_2)^\perp \\ \implies \langle x,v_1+v_2\rangle = 0 \ \forall v_1,v_2 \in V_1,V_2 \\
\implies   \langle x,v_1 \rangle = 0 \forall v_1 \in V_1 (\text{by putting $v_2 = 0$}) \implies x \in V_1^\perp \\
\implies  \langle x,v_2 \rangle = 0 \forall v_2 \in V_2 (\text{by putting $v_1 = 0$}) \implies x \in V_2^\perp \\
\implies x \in V_1^\perp \cap V_2^\perp
$$

The other way is similar:
$$
x \in V_1^\perp \cap V_2^\perp \\
\implies x \in V_1^\perp \implies \langle x,v_1 \rangle = 0 \forall v_1 \in V_1 \\
\implies x \in V_2^\perp \implies \langle x,v_2 \rangle = 0 \forall v_2 \in V_2 \\
\implies \langle x,v_1+v_2 \rangle = 0 \forall v_1,v_2 \in V_1,V_2 (\text{by adding the above}) \\
\implies x \in (V_1+V_2)^\perp
$$

Using the lead shown  here, I would like you to solve the other one yourself.